# Login page using HTML/CSS

Tags: css, html, authentication

Please help. I want a pure, simple html/css login form using latest technology like html5 and not using any database connection like sql, php, aspx, just plain simple login form. User id and password store like a text file or simple database like MS Access. I need the result to show if user name or password is incorrect to display a message like "Password incorrect" and if login successful to redirect to another page. Most examples/demo from the web only show login form and that it. Also, there's action="http://www.somesite.com" but it keep going to somesite.com no matter what I put in login and password. What do I need to change/add?

This is one of many same demo login forms I downloaded. Thank you for your help.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login1b.css">
</head>
<div id="wrapper">
<form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="http://www.somesite.com" method="post">
 <div class="header">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <span>Fill out the form below to login.</span>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
    <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" required />
     <div class="user-icon"></div>
     <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" required />
     <div class="pass-icon"></div>      
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" require />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="register" require />
 </div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="gradient"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: um ok. you can do this with HTML/CSS but without a database and server side script it will never *really* work. You could fake it in Javascript with hardcoded passwords and usernames but other people could never signup/signin to your site with out knowing those existing credentials

Comment: Where do you propose to store the users and passwords?  I don't see  how you can do this without some backend scripting like Node.js, php, .net, etc.

Comment: The only database HTML5 could connect to directly would be local storage, which would be rather pointless for storing passwords as it would only work on that one particular device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place in your protected directory an [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file that points to a plain text file with the `usernames` and their `hashed passwords`. The exact syntax depends on which web server you use - for `Apache cf`. its [reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/password_encryptions.html).

With `.htaccess` you don't need any HTML code - the browsers already have a built-in login form and can automatically handle the authentication process. This is a very basic and simplistic solution with some limitations (e.g., you can't logout, the session isn't kept alive for subsequent browser sessions, etc.).

If you need something quick and simple with no back-end development then this is probably a good, well-tested, and standard-compliant choice.